# How to fix exceptions during running stubrunner server on Spring Cloud CLI?

Tags: spring-cloud

I have generated stubs of contract tests via producer.
I have installed Spring Cloud CLI (version Spring Cloud CLI v2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT).
I have created file stubrunner.yml in path `C:\Work` with next properties:

```
stubrunner:
  stubsMode: LOCAL
  ids: com.project:users:+:stubs:8555
  repositoryRoot: classpath:m2repo/repository/
```

In command line I moved to whis path `C:\Work`and then type spring cloud stubrunner and as resut I got 2 exception messages

1-st exception:

```
o.s.c.l.deployer.DeployerApplication     : Starting DeployerApplication v2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT on User with PID 3144 (C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\org\springframework\cloud\launcher\spring-cloud-launcher-deployer\2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT\spring-cloud-launcher-deployer-2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar started by User in C:\Work)
o.s.c.l.deployer.DeployerApplication     : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
o.s.c.l.deployer.DeployerApplication     : Started DeployerApplication in 0.776624926 seconds (JVM running for 3.148)
o.s.cloud.launcher.deployer.Deployer     : Loaded YAML properties from: file [C:\Work\.\stubrunner.yml]
o.s.boot.loader.thin.PathResolver        : Extracting dependencies from: file:/C:/Users/User/.m2/repository/org/springframework/cloud/launcher/spring-cloud-launcher-stubrunner/2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/spring-cloud-launcher-stubrunner-2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar, with profiles []
o.s.boot.loader.thin.PathResolver        : Searching for properties in: file:/C:/Users/User/.m2/repository/org/springframework/cloud/launcher/spring-cloud-launcher-stubrunner/2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/spring-cloud-launcher-stubrunner-2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar
o.s.boot.loader.thin.PathResolver        : Extracting dependencies from: class path resource [META-INF/thin/empty-pom.xml], with profiles []
o.s.b.loader.thin.MavenSettingsReader    : Reading settings from: C:\Users\User\.m2\settings.xml
o.s.boot.loader.thin.DependencyResolver  : Computing dependencies from pom and properties
o.s.c.deployer.thin.ThinJarAppWrapper    : Cannot deploy org.springframework.cloud.launcher:spring-cloud-launcher-stubrunner:jar:2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [org.springframework.cloud.deployer.thin.ContextRunner] from ClassLoader [java.net.URLClassLoader@430df350]
        at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:476) ~[spring-core-5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.findMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:239) ~[spring-core-5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.cloud.deployer.thin.ThinJarAppWrapper.runContext(ThinJarAppWrapper.java:132) ~[spring-cloud-deployer-thin-1.0.22.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.cloud.deployer.thin.ThinJarAppWrapper.run(ThinJarAppWrapper.java:90) ~[spring-cloud-deployer-thin-1.0.22.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.cloud.deployer.thin.AbstractThinJarSupport.deploy(AbstractThinJarSupport.java:60) [spring-cloud-deployer-thin-1.0.22.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.cloud.deployer.thin.ThinJarAppDeployer.deploy(ThinJarAppDeployer.java:63) [spring-cloud-deployer-thin-1.0.22.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.cloud.launcher.deployer.Deployer.deployInternal(Deployer.java:203) [spring-cloud-launcher-deployer-2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.cloud.launcher.deployer.Deployer.deploy(Deployer.java:108) [spring-cloud-launcher-deployer-2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.cloud.launcher.deployer.DeployerApplication.launch(DeployerApplication.java:121) [spring-cloud-launcher-deployer-2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.cloud.launcher.deployer.DeployerApplication.run(DeployerApplication.java:64) [spring-cloud-launcher-deployer-2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.cloud.launcher.deployer.DeployerApplication.main(DeployerApplication.java:54) [spring-cloud-launcher-deployer-2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48) [spring-boot-thin-launcher-1.0.22.RELEASE-exec.jar:1.0.22.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87) [spring-boot-thin-launcher-1.0.22.RELEASE-exec.jar:1.0.22.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50) [spring-boot-thin-launcher-1.0.22.RELEASE-exec.jar:1.0.22.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.thin.ThinJarLauncher.launch(ThinJarLauncher.java:193) [spring-boot-thin-launcher-1.0.22.RELEASE-exec.jar:1.0.22.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.thin.ThinJarLauncher.main(ThinJarLauncher.java:140) [spring-boot-thin-launcher-1.0.22.RELEASE-exec.jar:1.0.22.RELEASE]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.wrapper.ThinJarWrapper.launch(ThinJarWrapper.java:140) [spring-cloud-launcher-deployer-2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.wrapper.ThinJarWrapper.main(ThinJarWrapper.java:107) [spring-cloud-launcher-deployer-2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
        at org.springframework.cloud.launcher.cli.LauncherCommand$LauncherOptionHandler.run(LauncherCommand.java:115) [spring-cloud-launcher-cli-2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.cli.command.options.OptionHandler.run(OptionHandler.java:85) [classes!/:2.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.cli.command.OptionParsingCommand.run(OptionParsingCommand.java:54) [classes!/:2.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.cli.command.CommandRunner.run(CommandRunner.java:219) [classes!/:2.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.cli.command.CommandRunner.runAndHandleErrors(CommandRunner.java:171) [classes!/:2.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.cli.SpringCli.main(SpringCli.java:64) [classes!/:2.1.7.RELEASE]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48) [spring-boot-thin-launcher-1.0.22.RELEASE-exec.jar:1.0.22.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87) [spring-boot-thin-launcher-1.0.22.RELEASE-exec.jar:1.0.22.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:51) [spring-boot-thin-launcher-1.0.22.RELEASE-exec.jar:1.0.22.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:52) [spring-boot-cli-2.1.7.RELEASE.jar:2.1.7.RELEASE]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/context/ConfigurableApplicationContext
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
        at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:458) ~[spring-core-5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        ... 43 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
        ... 47 common frames omitted
```

And 2-nd exception:

```
o.s.cloud.launcher.cli.LauncherCommand   : Error running spring cloud

java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
        at org.springframework.cloud.launcher.cli.LauncherCommand$LauncherOptionHandler.run(LauncherCommand.java:115) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.cli.command.options.OptionHandler.run(OptionHandler.java:85) [classes!/:2.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.cli.command.OptionParsingCommand.run(OptionParsingCommand.java:54) [classes!/:2.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.cli.command.CommandRunner.run(CommandRunner.java:219) [classes!/:2.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.cli.command.CommandRunner.runAndHandleErrors(CommandRunner.java:171) [classes!/:2.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.cli.SpringCli.main(SpringCli.java:64) [classes!/:2.1.7.RELEASE]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48) [spring-boot-cli-2.1.7.RELEASE.jar:2.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87) [spring-boot-cli-2.1.7.RELEASE.jar:2.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:51) [spring-boot-cli-2.1.7.RELEASE.jar:2.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:52) [spring-boot-cli-2.1.7.RELEASE.jar:2.1.7.RELEASE]
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.wrapper.ThinJarWrapper.launch(ThinJarWrapper.java:140) ~[spring-cloud-launcher-deployer-2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.wrapper.ThinJarWrapper.main(ThinJarWrapper.java:107) ~[spring-cloud-launcher-deployer-2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        ... 18 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48) [spring-boot-cli-2.1.7.RELEASE.jar:2.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87) [spring-boot-cli-2.1.7.RELEASE.jar:2.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50) [spring-boot-cli-2.1.7.RELEASE.jar:2.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.thin.ThinJarLauncher.launch(ThinJarLauncher.java:193) ~[spring-boot-thin-launcher-1.0.22.RELEASE.jar:1.0.22.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.thin.ThinJarLauncher.main(ThinJarLauncher.java:140) ~[spring-boot-thin-launcher-1.0.22.RELEASE.jar:1.0.22.RELEASE]
        ... 24 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [org.springframework.cloud.deployer.thin.ContextRunner] from ClassLoader [java.net.URLClassLoader@430df350]
        at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:476) ~[spring-core-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.findMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:239) ~[spring-core-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.findMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:218) ~[spring-core-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cloud.deployer.thin.ThinJarAppWrapper.isRunning(ThinJarAppWrapper.java:118) ~[spring-cloud-deployer-thin-1.0.22.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.cloud.deployer.thin.ThinJarAppWrapper.getState(ThinJarAppWrapper.java:218) ~[spring-cloud-deployer-thin-1.0.22.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.cloud.deployer.thin.InMemoryAppInstanceStatus.getState(ThinJarAppDeployer.java:206) ~[spring-cloud-deployer-thin-1.0.22.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.cloud.deployer.spi.app.AppStatus.getState(AppStatus.java:92) ~[spring-cloud-deployer-spi-1.1.4.RELEASE.jar:1.1.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cloud.launcher.deployer.Deployer.getAppStatus(Deployer.java:251) ~[spring-cloud-launcher-deployer-2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.cloud.launcher.deployer.Deployer.deployInternal(Deployer.java:204) ~[spring-cloud-launcher-deployer-2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.cloud.launcher.deployer.Deployer.deploy(Deployer.java:108) ~[spring-cloud-launcher-deployer-2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.cloud.launcher.deployer.DeployerApplication.launch(DeployerApplication.java:121) ~[spring-cloud-launcher-deployer-2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.cloud.launcher.deployer.DeployerApplication.run(DeployerApplication.java:64) ~[spring-cloud-launcher-deployer-2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.cloud.launcher.deployer.DeployerApplication.main(DeployerApplication.java:54) ~[spring-cloud-launcher-deployer-2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        ... 33 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/context/ConfigurableApplicationContext
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
        at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:458) ~[spring-core-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.9.RELEASE]
        ... 45 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
        ... 49 common frames omitted
```

in m2/repository settings.xml file has next text:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0" 
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">

<pluginGroups>
  </pluginGroups>

<proxies>
  </proxies>

<mirrors>
  </mirrors>

<profiles>  
  </profiles>
</settings>
```

What I need to do for starting stubrunner server voa Spring Cloud CLI?

Comment: It seems that you have a mismatch between Spring Boot and Spring Cloud CLI. That's why you have a missing class. Also you don't have a classpath entry of `m2repo` I guess. You should use LOCAL if you want to fetch stubs from the local m2.

Comment: Hi, Marcin. Thanks for your answer. Actualy I don't understand where Spring Boot should be. I found information about installation of Spring Cloud CLI but where Spring Boot shold be actualy I don't understand. Or may be I don't understand somethink else. I haven't so many experience in programming and many things I don't know. Colud you please clearify it for me. About having classpath entry of m2repo also not clearly for me where it shold be and how it looks like? About using LOCAL - in stubrunner.yml I already provided stubrunner:stubsMode:LOCAL. It's not thet what about you writing? Thanks

Comment: Please read the docs here https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-cli/2.2.0.M1/reference/html/ for Spring Cloud CLI and its dependence on Boot. Here https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-contract/2.2.0.M2/reference/html/project-features.html#features-stub-runner you can read about about stub runner and its options.

Answer (score 0):

Spring cloud cli 2.2.0 does not work with 2.3.1 spring boot CLI, try:

- Spring boot CLI 2.3.1.RELEASE
- Spring cloud CLI 2.2.1.RELEASE